# Dúvida Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Estou estudando Spring MVC, e estou desenvolvendo um sistema que conterá perguntas e respostas. Como que fica o Controller, crio um para PerguntasController e outro para RespostasController, ou apenas 1 para os dois

Answer (score 1):

Nesse seu sistema, o usuário irá realizar um pergunta e você irá devolver a resposta na mesma requisição, certo?

Se for isso, você terá apenas um Controller mesmo, ele irá receber a requisição do usuário com a pergunta, você irá processar em um Service, se precisar salvar algo no banco use o Repository e devolve a resposta para o controle que por sua vez irá retorna a resposta na requisição.

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende de como você está modelando o sistema. Você poderia por exemplo ter uma entidade única para gerenciar as questões, então ela trataria tanto as respostas como as perguntas.

Answer (score -1):

Isso é muito relativo a como você deseja modelar, complementando a resposta do Daniel acima, o dominio da aplicação deve reger as nomenclaturas caso você queira tratar perguntas e respostas o que caracteriza uma questão deveria adotar

"QuestionController" como nome.

Outra dica é utilizar nomes em inglês para nomenclaturas pois além da linguagem ser em inglês é uma ótima prática, futuramente você pode trabalhar em projetos globais e o inglês é uma lingua global presente em 80% dos códigos mundo a fora.